# PHP error_log still work inside switch with break

Tags: php, switch-statement, error-log

I thought i had a bug in my code but by isolating the problem i found out some 'weird' behaviour of error_log() inside a switch case.

I added some error_log for debugging, but then wehenever i was running throught the switch, the error_log would always be triggered even if the call was made outside of the valid case.

Here the exact part of my code that made me find out this wierdness:

```
switch($LLTP->request()){

  case 'json':
    /* some code commented out for debug here */
    error_log('json');
    echo 'json';
    break;

  default:
    /* some code commented out for debug here */
    error_log('html');
    echo 'html';
    break;
}
```

the request method is plain and simple and return a string like `'json','html','ajax'` etc..

```
 public function request(){
    return $this->requests;
  }
```

so if the switch is html, the default kick in and i get the expepted results:

> echoing 'html' (expected)
>
> errorlog 'html' (expected)

BUT when i run it with the 'json' switch, i get the expected 'json' on screen and inside the error_log, but i also get the 'html' error entry (without the echo).

> echoing 'json' (expected)
>
> errorlog 'json' (expected)
>
> errorlog 'html, referer: https://www.example.com/home.json' (unexpected)

Is this normal behavior? Fisrt time i notice it and if i try to reproduce the 'weirdness' with another sample code:

```
$vv='json';
switch($vv){
  case 'json':
    echo 'json';
    error_log('json');
    break;
  default:
    echo 'html';
    error_log('html');
    break;
}
```

i get, (in the errorlog)

> [error] json (expected)
>
> [error] json, referer: http://www.example.com/home.json (unexpeted as
>   it's the second entry in the log)

i'm lost, there something i don't understand or expected results is not what I expected.

PS: i don'T output the errors on the page, i only log errors in the logs. if this had anything to do with it o.O

Comment: It would be nice to know WHY people down vote. If you do, please explain.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Are timestamps the same in the error log?

Comment: yes, except sometimes they are 1 second apart.. What amaze me it i get totally different behavior than usual on this specific scenario. I even isolated includes, methods and functions for debug. Must be something i coded before hand. i'm just stunned as everything else works as expected. If i even find out i'll post my conclusion here

Comment: Also, the first occurence only show the string i passed. but the last log entry shows the referer after the string. See quoted logs above.

Comment: Can you reproduce it at command-line?

Comment: Did not try the command line but it started another code from scratch and still have the same behaviour. Still didn't find the cause of this minor weirdness. nothing to stop from going on. Carrying along... unless anyone have any inputs or similar behaviour we'll close the case.

Comment: Create a new file with minimum code to demonstrate the issue. Run it from command line and a under web-server (Apache) and compare the result. Share the file. I think the problem is in your additional code (`$LLTP` ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today i found out the reason behind this.

When i was testing i was spoofing a json request with my browser. But everytime i would hit refresh, my browser would also send a request for the favicon.ico file. Since i didn't add the mod_rewrite rules for images it was handled as an regular html request by the code, therefore calling the html part of the switch.